# How to combine multiple applications with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-swarm

Given the following setup of applications:

- App A: Docker-compose with a PostgreSQL image and a custom app image which uses that PostgreSQL image
- App B: Docker-compose with a PostgreSQL image and a custom app image which uses that PostgreSQL image

App B depends on App A, but App A could run and be tested in isolation without App B (and sometimes this is desired).

Is there a way to combine these different applications into a single Docker thing? I've read about stacks and bundles, but it's all a bit cryptic to me.

Comment: That would depend on what you actually want to do. You always could just make it one image which is kind of not what you want to do. What you might just be looking for is [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) from what I know about docker.

Comment: @Seth I thought that compose was used for building a single application composed of different services: such as a frontend, backend and database; here I have different (standalone) applications which happen to communicate to each other; kind of like microservices.

Comment: As you have an explicit dependency they're not just services that "happen to communicate with each other". Have a compose for App B. You could always just pull the individual image for A. Stacks and bundles are actually based on compose as you can see [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/).